# How do I disable jQuery dialog child elements from resizing independently?

Tags: jquery

I have a dialog box that I open using jQuery 1.7.1. The html for the dialog is:

```
<div id="transactionDialog" title="Transaction Contents">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#transactionDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    show: "highlight",
    resizable: true
});
```

How do I get rid of the resize icon on the `<textarea>` tag?

[image: dialog resize grippy]

Comment: I believe this is a function of the browser, and not your HTML.

Comment: If that is in Chrome I don't think you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little css might help

```
.ui-dialog textarea { 
    resize: none; 
}
```

and just to extend on this answer a little, if you want to hide that nasty highlight border in most browsers you can use a little more css

```
.ui-dialog textarea:focus { 
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using CSS: `textarea { resize:none }`

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is only for Chrome/Chromium browser. But you can fix it like this:

```
<div id="transactionDialog" title="Transaction Contents" style="resize: none;">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```